# Custom metabox for menu administration page?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, menus

I've been googleing around but failed to find a solution for my need. 
I'm using wordpress 3.0 and TwentyEleven theme as default pack. 
In the Dashboard -> appearance->menus  that allow user can create menu items from Pages,Categories,and custom link. 
Now I want to add a box like those boxes above but it would list my custom-post-type's taxonomy and metadata. How can I accomplish with this task ?

I know how to add metabox and taxonomy for custom post type but cannot do with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a follow up for anybody looking to add their own meta boxes to the menu screen, you can do it by using 'nav-menus' for the post type:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_add_meta_box' );

function my_add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'custom-meta-box', __('My meta box'), 'my_nav_menu_item_link_meta_box', 'nav-menus', 'side', 'default' );
}

function my_nav_menu_item_link_meta_box() {

    ?>
    <div class="custom-meta-box" id="custom-meta-box">
            Your meta box content goes here
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I hope that helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

From the WordPress Codex Site:

> Custom Post Types and Taxonomies
>
> If you have added custom post types and taxonomies, those types will also be available to add as menu items. If you don't see your custom post types or taxonomies, check the Screen Options to insure those modules are set to display.

You probably just have the display disabled. Try looking  at the Screen Options for the menu page.